# Obtain all the records in table A, if they meet the conditions with table B

Tags: mysql, select

I want to obtain last update (**max(bonus_records.id)**) of the each bonus (**bonus_records.uid - unique id**) then meet this conditions:

1. that have never been redeemed by indicated player
2. that have been redemed by indicated player but then the redemption count is less than **redeem_count**
   exceeded
3. The bonus redeemed and active at the said moment (is that bonus that has the fields **completed** and **canceled** at 0)

**Additional information:** If redeem_count is equal to 0, then there is no redemption limit for the said bonus

**This is the database basic structure:**

[image]

[**DB-FIDDLE**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qRJDSTTQAvkohRw2uPnozv/1)

[**DB-FIDDLE v2 (With @Solarflare query)**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qRJDSTTQAvkohRw2uPnozv/6)

[**DB-FIDDLE v3**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qRJDSTTQAvkohRw2uPnozv/8)

**My query that failing:**

```
SELECT MAX(br1.id) /* Get last update of bonus */,
    br1.uid,
    br1.name, 
    rb1.instance_id,
    rb1.player_id,
    br1.redeem_count,
    rb1.executed,
    rb1.completed,
    rb1.canceled
FROM 
    bonus_records br1
LEFT JOIN
    redeemed_bonuses rb1 ON 
    rb1.bonus_id = br1.id
WHERE 
    (rb1.player_id IS NULL) OR /* never redeemed */
    (rb1.player_id = 1 AND /* if redeemed then */
        (
            br1.redeem_count > ( /* total count of X redemed bonus is less then redeem_count but redeem_count <> 0 */
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM redeemed_bonuses rb2
                INNER JOIN bonus_records br2 ON rb2.bonus_id = br2.id
                WHERE br2.uid = br1.uid AND rb2.completed = 0 AND rb2.canceled = 0
            ) OR
            br1.redeem_count = 0 /* redeem_count = 0 means that there is no established limit of redeem  */
        )
    )
GROUP BY 
    br1.uid
```

**Expected result:**

**If i have this bonus list:**

[image]

**And this redeemed bonus list:**

[image]

**Then the expected outcome bonus list for player_id = 1 will be:**

[image]

Comment: In what way is your query is failing? E.g. do you get an error? Then add it. Do you get incorrect/unexpected results? Then add details about this (at least describe the problem - ideally you would need to add sample data for your tables plus expected result based on this data plus the result your get from this sample data). One thing that looks odd is `rb1.player_id = 1`, seems hardcoded but might have a different meaning than it implies. It is also vital if `bonus_records.uid` is actually unique as you said (as either `max(br1.id)` is a single value anyway, or `br1.name, ...` is undetermined)

Comment: Please look the Db-fiddle sample. I have put all the necesarry information. The id 1 can be another id. Since according to the player, I need to get all the bonuses that he can have available. And for that, the 3 conditions that I put above must be fulfilled

Comment: Thanks, that takes care of the sample data, sorry, I missed that. Still, could you clarify the problem? I assume you get unexpected result, so could you specify the expected outcome? Also, `uid` seems to not be unique (you should remove the "unique id" in "(bonus_records.uid - unique id)", it is misleading and/or means something different than you want to say), so the values for `br1.name, ...` in your `select` are not defined. They will be chosen from a random row in your group (or fail in MySQL 5.7+), and will not (neccessarily) be from the row with `max(id)` - is that maybe your problem?

Comment: Yes i get unexpected result.I will try to explain. Each player has the possibility to redeem different types of bonuses. The bonuses are differentiated with bonus_records.uid. Each bonus (bonus_records.uid) in turn can have different versions (for example at some point freespins = 10 and at another time freespins = 20), so when you want to show the list of bonuses to the player, you have to search always the last update (max (bonus_records.id)).

Comment: At the same time you have to look at what bonuses are available for the user and for that you have to fulfill the 3 fundamental conditions. For example, a "welcome" bonus will only be available once (when the user registers) therefore it will be necessary to check that the quantity of redeemed bonus (count (*) from redeem_bonuses inner join bonus_records on bonus_records.id = redeem_bonuses .bonus_id where bonus_id = X (which refers to the last available id of the "welcome" type bonus) and player_id = X) is less than bonus_records.redeem_count.

Comment: It's nice to have some background, but the question was: what is the expected result? E.g., with your sample data, could you create the expected resultset (I assume the counts are incorrect)? It's a lot easier so spot problems if you know the outcome, than to rethink and understand all your conditions. Also, do you want a player specific count? (As your first term isn't player specific)

Comment: @Solarflare i added the expected result by the correspondent data

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it cleared the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your query/logic:

- `select max(id), name, ... group by uid` will **not** give you the row with the maximum id. It will give you the maximum id, and the values of *any* row that is in that group. If there is only one row per group (e.g. if uid is unique/the primary key), that might be the one you are looking for, otherwise it is not determined (and will fail for MySQL 5.7), see [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) and any question on stackoverflow about an errormessage with [`sql_mode=only_full_group_by`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=this+is+incompatible+with+sql_mode%3Donly_full_group_by).
- `left join ... ON bonus_id = id where rb1.player_id IS NULL` will be false if there is *any* player that has redeemed this bonusid. If you included the playerid in the `on`-condition, it would be true if the player would not have redeemed *all* different ids for a given `uid` (which is probably impossible).
- something similar happens since you `join` via `rb1.bonus_id = br1.id` and apply your condition to this `id` (but not `uid`): if there is some old entry with a bigger `redeem_count`, it evaluates to true even if there is a latest id with a lower `redeem_count` (that won't be part of the `group by`, since you filtered it out).
- instead, you probably would need to apply your filter after `left join`, e.g using `group by ... having ...` or `select ... from (select ... group by ...) where ...`

With this said, I won't fix your query (although it may be salvageable), but write you a new one with a new structure.

Breaking it into steps, first, get a list of all active bonuses:

```
select * from bonus_records br
where not exists 
  (select 1 from bonus_records br1
   where br1.uid = br.uid and br1.id > br.id);
```

Next step is to check how often a specific uid has been redeemed by a specific player (the `uid`-information is obtained by checking the `bonus_records`-table):

```
select br.uid, count(*) 
from redeemed_bonuses rb
join bonus_records br on br.id = rb.bonus_id
where rb.player_id = 1
   and not (rb.completed = 0 and rb.canceled = 0) 
group by br.uid;
```

The condition `not (rb.completed = 0 and rb.canceled = 0)` is adepted to fit the requirements according to the comments.

Now join those two and apply your conditions about the actual count being lower than `redeem_count`:

```
select pb.*, rd.actual_count from 
  (select * from bonus_records br
   where not exists 
     (select 1 from bonus_records br1
      where br1.uid = br.uid and br1.id > br.id)
  ) pb -- active potential bonuses
left join  
  (select br.uid, count(*) as actual_count 
   from redeemed_bonuses rb
   join bonus_records br on br.id = rb.bonus_id
   where rb.player_id = 1
      and not (rb.completed = 0 and rb.canceled = 0) 
   group by br.uid
  ) rd -- redeemed bonuses by that user
on pb.uid = rd.uid 
where rd.actual_count is null            -- uid never redeemed (left join empty)
   or rd.actual_count < pb.redeem_count  -- still some remaining
   or pb.redeem_count = 0                -- unlimited bonus
```

Comment: I thank you for your time and effort. I have done the test and although it seems that you are close to obtaining the correct result, some things fail. For example, it returns the welcome bonus, but it should not because it has already been redeemed by the player and has redemption limit of. And another fail is that it does not return the deposit100 bonus, because although it has a redemption limit, we have it as an active bonus that has not been canceled or completed (completed = 0 or canceled = 0) by the player

Comment: As aditional information, the player can have only one active bonus.

Comment: Could you update your dbfiddle with a testcase that doesn't work (as currently it doesn't match your example, so I couldn't test it - e.g. user 1 has redeemed bonusid 1 and 2 which do not exist). At least the welcome bonus should work as expected, as it is straight forward, so I might have misunderstood something. About the (`completed = 0 or canceled = 0)`, I mentioned that I took that condition from your original query (`completed = 0 and canceled = 0)`, so if it is different, you may have to adjust it accordingly (feel free to edit the answer) and if you update the testcase, I can test it.

Comment: i added the db-fiddle v2 to initial post.

Comment: sorry i have change again the db-fiddle example. Still failing. I will try to fix it.

Comment: The fail is with my condition "and (rb.completed = 0 and rb.canceled = 0) ". If i put operator OR, i get correct result but if i put AND, i get the welcome_bonus, but i dont understand why, because the welcome_bonus is marked es completed = 1

Comment: My first alternative, judging from the column names, was `(rb.completed = 1 and rb.canceled = 0)` (maybe adding checks for `null`?), and it seems to fit to your data; does that give you your expected result? The goal for that term is that it should be "true" if that row should count as a redeemed bonus (and thus increasing the count by 1), you need to find the right combination to describe when you want it to count (e.g. "only counts when completed but not canceled", which would be `(rb.completed = 1 and rb.canceled = 0)`).

Comment: The redeemed bonus can be completed or canceled by the player. If completed and canceled are equal to 0, then, it means that the bonus is active.

Comment: i have added other combinations of bonus for player 1, where the welcome bonus is not redeemed so, the result need to return the welcome_bonus too but it doesn't. You can get the example in db-fiddle v3 in initial post. I share you the image of redeemed_bonuses too. https://imgur.com/1Bsx2Hf

Comment: "If completed and canceled are equal to 0, then, it means that the bonus is active" translates to `not (rb.completed = 0 and rb.canceled = 0)`, which is equivalent to `(rb.completed = 1 or rb.canceled = 1)`. [There are only a limited number of combinations. When you tell me for the 4 combinations (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1) what the outcome is (active or not), I can tell you the formula - this might be faster than retrying or reexplaining. It really just depends on how you want to define it. There also is a column "executed" - if it is relevant, don't forget it :-) ]

Comment: You're right! After change to **and not (rb.completed = 0 and rb.canceled = 0)**  I have done several tests and it seems that now it is working perfectly. I've been trying for 4 days to resolve the problem and you've helped me a lot! I hope I have not bothered you much. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Solarflare, can you tell me why the value of **rd.actual_count** in the main select is NULL or if i add another field like **rd.executed** i get again as NULL value of that field.

Comment: `actual_count` is the number of redeemed bonuses of that uid (and just a helper column); `null` means 0, if you prefer 0, try `coalesce(rd.actual_count,0)`, but that's borderlining on a different question (as not really relevant to your original problem). Showing `executed` makes no sense (see the 1st point in my answer): if a player has a uid redeemed twice - which of the 2 potential values of executed should be displayed? If you want additional conditions/data/results, it's probably time to ask a new question (including current and expected result); you can link to this one for background.